# jQuery. .load() won't give a response/status

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, load

```
var destino = '#myContainer';

var file = 'my-file.html'; //file exists in folder.
var seccion = 'myTarget';    //
var nivel   = 1;      // #myTarget_1 exists in document


$('.load').show();
console.log('before');
$(destino).load('/'+file+' #'+seccion+'_'+nivel, function(response, status, xhr){
    $('.load').hide();
    console.log(response);
    console.log(status);
}
console.log('done');
```

log output:

```
before
done
```

Why is it posible that this doesn't return anything? No error or content. Can I forze it somehow to get an error if there is one?

Comment: Your code does not show the variable `archivo`. Is this a typo or you meant to use `file` ?

Comment: you're right i was translating some code to english for better understanding. thanks

Comment: use $.ajaxSetup() to set the required callbacks.

Comment: is it desitno or destino? There's a typo in your code. Also seccion already has a hash in it, so you're trying to load ##myTarget.

Comment: sorry, yes, there are typos i made when copying and translating here...   @deostroll can you post as an answer the equivalent? i don't think ajaxSetup lets load a tarjeted div, does it?

Comment: One more thing - is my-file.html located in the web root, or next to the JS file? What happens if you remove the forward slash? And is the .load div being hidden?

Comment: When you load in Firebug, can you at least see that the request is being made?

Comment: if i remove the slash it happens the same. the folder is in the same path as username (if  /index.html then /my-file-html and ../js/the-javascript.js )

Comment: In which case, it's not executing at all. If you go to the 'script' tab in Firebug, can you see the script? Also, is this whole block inside a `$(document).ready()` block?

Comment: There is a space char before `#`

Comment: the space before #: that is normal, it's to tarjet the div (http://api.jquery.com/load/) @Blowski yes is inside a $(document).ready() but i can't understand why not; firebug does not jump any errors

Comment: And the script is definitely being loaded? Can you see it inside the list of scripts on the 'scripts' tab? And you don't have JavaScript disabled by something like the Developer toolbar? (These are all facepalming mistakes I do frequently.)

Comment: yup i have a console.log('about to make the load') right before the load and i can see it; you may check that here http://www.idiso.com/extranet/hm/gen/gran-melia/es/index.html and look how funny, check here aswell http://www.idiso.com/extranet/hm/gen/gran-melia/es/sobre-nosotros.html (works, same code, different URL)

Comment: edited question with console.log's and their outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments above, the element on which you are calling `$.load()` is dynamically named. Therefore, ensure that the element exists before doing the load. e.g.

```
if($(destino)) {
   $(destino).load();
} else {
   console.log(destino + ' does not exist');
}
```

The alternative is to do as @Armin said, and use `$.get()` and then `$.appendTo()` as a success callback.

Comment: the element on which you are calling $.load() is dynamically named; you mean #myContainer?? if so, that is not correct. is statically created and named

Comment: That's going to be my guess. If the load is never being run, it suggests the selector is returning null.

Comment: that is the issue!!!!! $(destino).length returns 0! at least now i know what is going on!

Answer (score 2):

Use `.get()` instead of `.load()`. As I have understood the `.load()` function, it is pasting the specified result directly to defined node. There is no callback function necessary.

**Load-Example:**

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html#whatever');
```

The content id #whatever on this page will be pasted to #result of the current page.

---

**Get-Example:**

```
var url = '/' + file;
$.get(url , function(data) {
    $('.load').hide();
    console.log($(data).find('#' + seccion + '_' + nivel));
});
```